# "e.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function" when jquery.trigger 2.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

since updating to jQuery 2.2.1 I am getting the following error in my tests.

> TypeError: e.stopImmediatePropagation is not a function

**The function where it is called:**

```
items.on('dragstart.h5s', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  if (options.dragImage) {
    _attachGhost(e.originalEvent, {
      item: options.dragImage,
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    });
    console.log('WARNING: dragImage option is deprecated' +
    ' and will be removed in the future!');
  } else {
    // add transparent clone or other ghost to cursor
    _getGhost(e.originalEvent, $(this), options.dragImage);
  }
  // cache selsection & add attr for dragging
  dragging = $(this);
  dragging.addClass(options.draggingClass);
  dragging.attr('aria-grabbed', 'true');
  // grab values
  index = dragging.index();
  draggingHeight = dragging.height();
  startParent = $(this).parent();
  // trigger sortstar update
  dragging.parent().triggerHandler('sortstart', {
    item: dragging,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    startparent: startParent
  });
});
```

**The test from where this is tested:**

```
it('should correctly run dragstart event', function(){
  $ul.sortable({
    'items': 'li',
    'connectWith': '.test',
    placeholderClass: 'test-placeholder',
    draggingClass: 'test-dragging'
  });

  $li.trigger(jQuery.Event( 'dragstart', {
    originalEvent: {
      pageX: 100,
      pageY: 100,
      dataTransfer: {
        setData: function(val){
          this.data = val;
        }
      }
    }
  }));

  assert.equal($li.attr('aria-grabbed'),'true');
  assert.isTrue($li.hasClass('test-dragging'));

});
```

Comment: Try `e.originalEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, since you are creating the `originalEvent` object your self that does not have the normal event related methods.

When we call the jQuery event object's `stopImmediatePropagation` method, it will try to call the same method of the original event object, since the method is not found it results in the error.

One possible solution here is to create a [custom event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)

```
var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
event.initEvent('dragstart', true, true);
event.pageX = 100;
event.pageY = 100;
event.dataTransfer = {
  setData: function(val) {
    this.data = val;
  }
};

$li.trigger(jQuery.Event(event));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b1fyzscu/4/)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a stopImmediatePropagation function to your originalEvent object since that's where it tries to fire it from according to [these docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

> Certain events may have properties specific to them. Those can be accessed as properties of the event.originalEvent object.

Answer (score 0):

A simple may be naive solution:

```
if (event.stopImmediatePropagation)
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```